# Why does my QTableWidgetItems's rowHeight not get properly set on refresh?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I'm creating a table widget that I want to auto-refresh at certain intervals. The trouble I'm having is that refreshing the contents of the table is resetting their rowHeight property and ignoring the call to setRowHeight().

For example, I have a repeater class here running on a separate thread:

```
class RepeatedTimer(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super(RepeatedTimer, self).__init__(obj)
        self.obj = obj
        self.stop = False
    def run(self):
        while not self.stop:
            time.sleep(2)
            self.obj.refresh()
```

and it's being used in my QTableWidget like this:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys, time

class TestTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestTable, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setColumnCount(1)
        self.thread = RepeatedTimer(self)  # Create the auto-refresher thread
        self.thread.start() # Start the thread
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        print "Clearing table"
        while self.rowCount():
            self.removeRow(0)
        for each in xrange(3):
            self.insertRow(each)
            text = str(time.time())
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(text)
            self.setItem(each, 0, item)
        for row in xrange(self.rowCount()):
            self.setRowHeight(row, 100)  # This part is not behaving as expected
            print 'Row %d height: %d' % (row, self.rowHeight(row))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print 'Stopping thread...'
        self.thread.stop = True
        self.thread.exit()


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
test = TestTable()
test.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you run this, you'll see that each time the table refreshes, it clears all the contents, adds new items in each row, and sets all the row heights to 100. Except that last part. It is correctly looping through the rows because it prints each time. But for some reason it stops setting the row heights after the first loop.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to create a thread to update the `QTableWidget`, you could use a `QTimer`, on the other hand remove `QTableWidgetItem` and set them again is expensive so I recommend you update them.

```
import sys
import time

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class TestTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestTable, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setRowCount(3)
        self.setColumnCount(1)

        for row in range(self.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.columnCount()):
                self.setItem(row, col, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(time.time())))

        for each in range(self.rowCount()):
            self.setRowHeight(each,   100)
            self.setColumnWidth(each, 250)

        timer_refresh = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer_refresh.timeout.connect(self.refresh)
        timer_refresh.start(2000)

    def refresh(self):
        for row in range(self.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.columnCount()):
                self.item(row, col).setText(str(time.time()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app  = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = TestTable()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is the QTimer blocking? I can't have anything blocking the main thread as the user still needs to be able to interact with the UI between refreshes.

Comment: @Shalinar 
QTimer is not blocking, is GUI-friendly :), try my answer and if I help you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: Awesome thank you yes I just got to work and tested it. Much simpler :) Unfortunately I believe I do have to keep the item replacement because of the nature of the data and its display, but it's a small enough table so it's not heavy enough to matter. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you do not need a separate thread for this task.

Use the QTimer class provides repetitive and single-shot timers.

Here is an example, sorry for me PyQt5

```
import sys
import time
#from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *

class TestTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestTable, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget setRowHeight ")
        self.resize(530, 330);

        self.setRowCount(3)
        self.setColumnCount(1)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['time.time())',])  
        for each in range(3):
            self.setRowHeight(each,   100)
            self.setColumnWidth(each, 250)

        self.my_qtimer = QTimer(self)
        self.my_qtimer.timeout.connect(self.timerTick)
        self.my_qtimer.start(1000)                     # msec

    def timerTick(self):
        for each in range(3):
            item = QTableWidgetItem(str(time.time()))
            self.setItem(0, each, item) 

app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
test = TestTable()
test.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]